# Does flying a drone close to the ground affect signal quality?

Tags: multirotor, first-person-view, video-transmitters, video-signal, interference

If I were to fly a drone over a large, flat field and there was nothing blocking Line of sight to the drone, would flying at close proximity to the ground impact the FPV video reception? would flying the drone higher up result in better signal?

I feel like I've heard that proximity to the ground can disrupt signal, but I can't find any sources of information about it.

Comment: I think this is a good question, and a good mirror, but I believe it's a duplicate.

Comment: @ifconfig I don't really think the question is a duplicate, but I just saw that one of the answers to that question answers this question. So, yeah, that answers my question.

Comment: I agree it's not strictly speaking a duplicate, but an answer to this would be faily similar in content to the ones there, IMO.